# Tomcat dies suddenly, Duplicate

Tags: tomcat8, fedora-22

i know this question already ask before and i already read this question :

1. [Tomcat Dies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9132496/tomcat-dies-suddenly)
2. [debugging tomcat crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575730/debugging-tomcat-crash)

But i still not understand..

I am using Fedora 22 And Tomcat 8.

My Tomcat dies suddenly without any error and i don't know why?

there's no any log in `catalina.out` or some file.

How can i know or debugging my tomcat to get more log, why my tomcat died suddenly..

and for additional information, i am using Apache-Activemq too..

maybe because of this or not?

Comment: type dmesg and look at system logs

Answer (score 1):

I always had a lot of problems with a server developed in house in a old job. This problem smells like them, JVM crashes, but you need to investigate better.

You can starts looking for hs_err_pidNNNN.log files across file system. -It can be into JAVA_HOME folder used by your Tomcat or TOMCAT_HOME directory.

```
find / -name "hs_err_pid*"
```

Select all hs_err_pid files found with approximated date and time with Tomcat fall. After analyse them following the [Troubleshooting Guide for Java SE](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/felog-138657.html). Give special attention for "C.5.4 Heap Summary" session.

In my case the crash was caused by "lack perm gen". The solution was increase this memory area with -XX:PermSize and -XX:MaxPermSize parameters.

Good luck!

Comment: Also check dmesg to see if the kernel is killing it for out-of-memory.

Comment: i don't see any file with name  `hs_err_pidNNNN.log` , i don't get any result after use this `find / -name "hs_err_pid*"`